# Adding fat to Konnyaku block recipe?

Tags: japanese-cuisine, gelling-agents, konjac

Konjac or Konnyaku blocks are bland but I notice an unpleasant alkaline flavor.
However the texture is very useful in many dishes.

Can I improve flavor of home-made blocks by adding oil?
Or will that prevent gelling at some percentage?

Recipe searches turn up only readymade blocks in dishes with added oil.